# Are character pointer allowed in python?

Tags: python, c++

I am using C++ based library where its return type is char pointer. I am calling this C++ function from within Python.

My question is that can I delete the memory allocated in C++ function from Python?

Python code

```
    lib.TagGetName.restype = c_char_p
    lib.TagGetName.argtypes=[c_int]
    data = 1
    cmt = (b"this is comment for Voltage")
    result = lib.TagGetName(data)
```

Python Output

```
Kernel process terminated for restart. (0)
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) on Windows (32 bits).
This is the IEP interpreter.
Type 'help' for help, type '?' for a list of *magic* commands.
```

Running script: "D:\QTDev\test.py"

```
1
SELECT sTagName FROM TagDataInfo where iTagId = 1;
Return value--> b'Voltage\xfd\xfd\xfd\xfd\xdd`\x18x'

print ("Return value-->" , result)
```

C++ Function Code

```
USE_MATH char* TagGetName(int iTagId)
{

    char* cName;
    //string cName = "";
    sqlite3_stmt               *stmtCreate = NULL;
    sqlite3                     *m_pdbObj;

    cout<<iTagId<<endl;
   if (sqlite3_open_v2("D:\\QTDev\\forPythonDLL\\Neha_Test_Use\\TagData", &m_pdbObj, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        return cName;
    }

   char cQuery[1024] = {0};
   sprintf(cQuery,"SELECT sTagName FROM TagDataInfo where iTagId = %d;",iTagId);
cout<<cQuery<<endl;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_pdbObj, cQuery, -1, &stmtCreate, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_step(stmtCreate);
            if(sqlite3_column_text(stmtCreate, 0))
            {

                cName = new char[strlen((char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmtCreate, 0))+1];
                memset(cName,0x00,(strlen((char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmtCreate, 0))+1));
                memcpy(cName,(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmtCreate, 0),strlen((char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmtCreate, 0)));
                cout<<"Cname="<<cName<<endl;
                cout<<"Database Name="<<(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmtCreate, 0)<<endl;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(stmtCreate);
        }
        else 
        {
            return cName; 
        }

    sqlite3_exec(m_pdbObj, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
    return cName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python you can't delete the memory being allocated in C++.
You will have to export another function from C++ which will just wrap the free()/delete call, and call that from python.

As an aside, remember that python is using UTF-16 and C++ may be using UTF-8, and some string conversion will be needed ( ctype can do this properly )

Comment: i have updated my code. please have a look on it.. and just suggest me if m doing wrong

Comment: Please compile with All Warnings enabled, and use a tool like valgrind to check memory leaks.